# Why my CSS file isn't loading on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I've created a very simple Node-RED flow as the following:

[image]

```
[{"id":"f2550b94.38775","type":"http in","z":"92cd7f6.acf58","name":"","url":"mypage","method":"get","upload":true,"swaggerDoc":"","x":150,"y":1820,"wires":[["d996137.45dc0f"]],"icon":"node-red/file-out.svg"},{"id":"34382576.899c32","type":"http response","z":"92cd7f6.acf58","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":435,"y":1820,"wires":[],"l":false},{"id":"d996137.45dc0f","type":"template","z":"92cd7f6.acf58","name":"HTML","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"html","syntax":"mustache","template":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\">\n</head>\n<body>\n    <h1>This is a heading</h1>\n    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>\n</body>\n</html>","output":"str","x":310,"y":1820,"wires":[["34382576.899c32"]],"icon":"node-red/parser-html.svg"},{"id":"d0acb79c.4200f8","type":"http in","z":"92cd7f6.acf58","name":"","url":"style.css","method":"get","upload":true,"swaggerDoc":"","x":150,"y":1860,"wires":[["7ff54806.73b928"]],"icon":"node-red/file-out.svg"},{"id":"750110.a3e6c6f","type":"http response","z":"92cd7f6.acf58","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{"content-type":"text/css"},"x":435,"y":1860,"wires":[],"l":false},{"id":"7ff54806.73b928","type":"template","z":"92cd7f6.acf58","name":"CSS","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"css","syntax":"mustache","template":"body {\n    background-color: lightblue;\n}\n\nh1 {\n    color: navy;\n    margin-left: 20px;\n}","output":"str","x":310,"y":1860,"wires":[["750110.a3e6c6f"]],"icon":"node-red/parser-html.svg"}]
```

The HTML code inside it is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css code inside it:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

For some reason, the HTML code on Node-RED is not loading the css style on my `style.css` page. I know this example works perfectly with separated files (without Node-RED), and I also know that if I serve the `style.css` file with Nodejs instead of using Node-RED the style will load correctly. So I believe this is a specific issue with Node-RED... Am I missing something on how it works? Why the css style is not loading on `mypage`?

---

The page as it should be:

[image]

The page as Node-RED shows:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the browsers console for any error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-type` header on the response to "text/css"

How to set headers is described in the side bar for the `http-out` node:

> **Inputs**
>
> - payload *string*
>     The body of the response.
> - statusCode *number*
>     If set, this is used as the response status code. Default: 200.
> - headers *object*
>     If set, provides HTTP headers to include in the response.
> - cookies *object*
>     If set, can be used to set or delete cookies.
>
> **Details**
>
> The statusCode and headers can also be set within the node itself. If
>   a property is set within the node, it cannot be overridden by the
>   corresponding message property.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working... I've updated the JSON sample on my answer where I'm doing as you said setting the `Content-Type` to `text/css` on the `http-out` node of the css code, but I still see the same error on the console. I've tried restarting Node-RED but it didn't work too...

Comment: It worked now. I don't know why but it doesn't work when the css page is named `style.css`... Any other name works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Clear the browser cache